# window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL always fails

Tags: file, camera, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL but for some reason my failure callback is always triggered. The success callback is never triggered. This is my code:

```
// Take a picture using the camera
  $scope.takePicture = function () {
    var options = { 
      quality: 100, 
      targetWidth: 500, 
      targetHeight: 500, 
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG, 
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true, 
      correctOrientation: true, 
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
      allowEdit: true 
    };

    navigator.camera.getPicture(
      cameraSuccess,
      cameraFailure,
      options
    );
    return false;
  };



// what to do when the camera has successfully yielded a good image
  function cameraSuccess(imageURI){ 
    alert('this is imageURI: ' + imageURI); 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, resolvePhotoPath, fail); 
  };
```

When I alert the imageURI, I get something like this:

file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1395126124474.jpg

I can confirm that when I look at that path using the Files application on an android, the file is indeed there. But when the code runs and it executes the window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL, the fail callback is always triggered with an error of
{"code":5}.

I've seen that that means there's an ENCODING_ERR but a bit baffled as to what is causing that. The file does save properly to that location so I am at a loss at to why the code will fail.

Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug within the camera plugin (I don't think it's supposed to store images there).

That being said, there is a workaround.

1. Install the org.apache.cordova.file-system-roots plugin
2. Add `<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />` to your config.xml
3. Rebuild your app